# iOS 8 Location services in MapBox

Tags: ios8, mapbox

I'm using MakBox for iOS 1.4.1 SDK in my iPhone app with Objective C.
In updating my app for XCode 6 and iOS 8 I added the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription item to my plist settings.  I tested and did not receive any location updates.  I then added the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key and that enabled updates to "flow".  My question is: Since I don't need location services when the app isn't running I'd like to just use the WhenInUse permission but MapBox doesn't appear to work.  So, if forced to use AlwaysUsage Apple throws the scary waring permission question about the app using location services even when the app is running.

Am I missing something here?

Edit - My location updates come from my RMMapViewDelegate methods.  If I use the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and the user allows always permission I get the updates.  If I use the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription I get nothing.
Edit - I added CLLocationManagerDelegate to my VC and properly spelled NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription and if I call [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] I will get the prompt and WhenInUse location updates will work.

Answer (score 0):

> I tested and did not receive any location updates.

Are you evaluating the response to this in an asynchronous way? That is, listening to the location manager delegate for an authorization status change? If not, this could be your problem.

Comment: ** Prev edit expired --- Not exactly what you mean.  I wasn't calling LocationManager directly, the MapView did it all and I call  mapView.showsUserLocation = TRUE;
                                               mapView.userTrackingMode = RMUserTrackingModeFollow;             And then I would receive location updates from the MapView.  Now unless I have the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key in my plist and the user checks the "always" permission I don't receive any location updates.